# Вычисление площади прямоугольника по двум точкам

Tags: javascript, математика

> Цель задания: Научиться совместно применять переменные, математические
> операторы и функции объекта Math.

> Задание: Запишите в переменные x и y
> координаты двух произвольных точек: x1, y1 — первая точка, x2, y2 —
> вторая точка.
> **Вычислите площадь прямоугольника, противоположные углы
> которого представлены указанными точками**. Выведите результат с помощью
> console.log. Проверка результата Для проверки подставляйте разные
> значения в переменные x1, y1, x2, y2 и смотрите на получившуюся
> площадь.

> Примеры для проверки:

```
Для x1 = 2, y1 = 3, x2 = 10, y2 = 5 площадь равна 16;
Для x1 = 10, y1 = 5, x2 = 2, y2 = 3 площадь равна 16
Для x1 = -5, y1 = 8, x2 = 10, y2 = 5 площадь равна 45; 
Для x1 = 5, y1 = 8, x2 = 5, y2 = 5 площадь равна 0; 
Для x1 = 8, y1 = 1, x2 = 5, y2 = 1 площадь равна 0
```

Не удаётся реализовать решение задачи из-за проблем с использованием формулы.

```
let x1 = 10
let y1 = 2

let x2 = -3
let y2 = 3

let cathetus = Math.abs(x1 - x2)
let cathetus = Math.abs(y1 - y2)

console.log(Math.sqrt(
  Math.pow(cathetus1, 2) + Math.pow(cathetus2, 2)
))
```

Comment: @АлексейШиманский К сожалению, могу поставить только один минус.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

использованна математическая формула была сложность в её поиске.

```
let rectangleArea = Math.abs(x1 - x2) * Math.abs(y1 - y2);
console.log(rectangleArea);

// let  x1 = 2, y1 = 3, x2 = 10, y2 = 5 //площадь равна 16;
// let x1 = 10, y1 = 5, x2 = 2, y2 = 3 //площадь равна 16;
let x1 = -5, y1 = 8, x2 = 10, y2 = 5 //площадь равна 45;
// let  x1 = 5, y1 = 8, x2 = 5, y2 = 5 //площадь равна 0;
// let  x1 = 8, y1 = 1, x2 = 5, y2 = 1 //площадь равна 0
```